# How to properly pull from a database using Django and template tags

Tags: django, django-templates, django-database

I'm trying to create a web application using Django that displays information about employees and schedules. I have the data for the employees stored in the Django database but when I try to pull from it and display information in a table nothing happens. I don't get an error so I'm not sure if I'm using the right methods or not.

I haven't used Django before so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I'm currently writing the script to pull from the database and display in the html page it's supposed to show up in while using a python file to store the Django template tag. I tried before just pulling data from the database from the html file but was unable to since I needed to import my django model libraries and couldn't do that on html.

I have the code split into two parts. The script that does the query is in my tag template labeled DatabaseQueryScript which is as follows:

```
@register.filter(name='PullEmployees')
  def PullEmployeesFromDatabase():
    AllEmployees = Profile.objects.all()
    return AllEmployees
```

Then I call the function in the html file

````
{% load DatabaseQueryScript %}
{%for employee in PullEmployees%}
 ```printing data to a table on screen```
{%endfor%}
````

I expect to be able to see a list of employees on the table when I open the page but right now there's nothing on the table beside the header I added before I execute the query.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be doing this inside template filters or template tags. They exist to modify the behaviour of the template, or to make changes to the data already passed to the template.

You will want to be querying your database from within your view. You can either use the appropriate generic class-based view, in this case ListView, or add it to  your context.

Use ListView like this:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class ListAllEmployees(ListView):
  model = Profile
```

Then in your template you can iterate through all your "Profiles" with `{% for profile in object_list %}` for example.

Or you can add it your context which will pass it to the template:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

class ListAllEmployees(TemplateView):
  def get_context_data(self):
    ctx = super().get_context_data()
    ctx['profiles'] = Profile.objects.all()
    return ctx
```

And then you can iterate through that in your template like: `{% for profile in profiles %}`.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems like you have misunderstood how to use Django Template Filters. A filter is something that you use to modify or interact with an object.

If you look at the existing built in filters you can find [multiple examples](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#capfirst).

E.g.

```
{{value|capfirst}}  # Converts a string stored in value, to be capitalized.
```

In your particular case, you probably just want to add a list of database items to your template context. There are multiple ways to do this depending on if you're using functional views or class based views.

When you finally have the variable defined in your context you can just do the following (where `object_list` is an example name of a context variable).

```
{% for obj in object_list %}
```

### Class Based List View

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
class EmployeeListView(ListView):
    model = Employee
    template = "/mytemplate.html"
```

In this case, the ListView would automatically add all employees in a template variable called `object_list`.

### Override get_context_data

If you're not using a `ListView` or don't want to rely on the inherited automation of creating the list of objects, you can override the `get_context_data()` method within your generic view.

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
class EmployeeView(TemplateView):
    template = "/mytemplate.html"

    def get_context_data(self):
        context = super().get_context_data()
        context["employee_list"] = self.get_queryset()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Profile.objects.all()
```

### Using Functional Views

In the case of functional views you will just pass in the context as a kwarg to your render function.

```
def employee_view(request):
    return render(request, '/mytemplate.html', {'employee_list': get_queryset()})

def get_queryset():
    return Profile.objects.all()
```